# Динамическое создание объектов

Tags: java

Хотел бы узнать, почему этот код не скомпилируется, и где можно подробнее почитать про динамическое создание объектов в `java`?

Объекты создаются и исчезают во время работы приложений. А сам код компилируется до запуска приложения, соответственно, я думаю, что этот код не компилируется из-за того, что он пытается засунуть в массив объекты, которых еще не существует на момент компиляции.

```java
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car[] arr = {new Car(), new Car()};
    }

    public class Car {
    }
}
```

Comment: Объекты создаются и исчезают во время работы приложений.А сам код компилируется до запуска приложения,соотвественно я думаю,что этот код не компилируется из-за того,что он пытается засунуть в массив объекты,которых еще не существует на момент компиляции

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45380615/7485582

Answer (score -1):

Так компилируется(- значит и работает)

```
package helpso_stat;

/**
 *
 * @author papa
 */
public class HelpSO_stat {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Car[] arr = {new Car(), new Car()};
    }
    public static class Car {
    }
    
}
```

Не компилировалась - потому что не нестатичная переменная(внутри это конечно адрес в памяти,указывающий на блок элементов(массив)) не может быть записана в статичной области(main()).Динамическое означает что все так сказать кирпичики класса(его численные параметры и байт-коды методов) будут считываться JVM+JRE(Java Runtime ... - платформой Java) вовремя работы программы,а скажем не будут жестко записаны компилятором в главный модуль)Типа <статичный обект>:=create <Car адрес в файле>,<динамическое>:= new <строка> "Car".JVM ищет файл Car.class считывает кирпичики - вот и обьект)